# Is there a way reduce the Email Delay of PHP Mail()

Tags: php, email

I am using a fastcomet website, and I am trying to create a feedback messaging system.

I have created the following function, for organizing a template for sending emails along with the headers accompanied to it.

**send_email.php**

```
<?php
function send_email($to,$from,$title,$sending_message){

$message="<html><body>";
$message.=$sending_message;
$message.="</body></html>";

$headers = "From: ". $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from ."\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path:".  $from . " \r\n";
$headers .= "CC:\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC:\r\n";

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

return mail($to, $title,$message,$headers);

}

?>
```

With other pages, I use the following code `include 'send_email.php'`, and use the function `send_email($to, $title,$message,$headers)`, and it works. The only problem is that the receival of the email either takes too long, or arbitrary in nature.

Sometimes, I test the feedback system by sending 3 emails. For example: Email1, Email2, Email3 are sent in the following order. Sometimes, I'll receive Email3 first than Email1 or Email2 first than Email3.

In terms of time, sometimes I'll receive the email in a few minutes, but some in a few hours which makes testing difficult because I am not able to know the results of the code until a few hours, which leaves me to wonder whether my code worked or not.

Note:

- By using the following code `echo "<p>". error_get_last()['message'] . "</p>";` I am able to figure out that the function did run successfully.

  - I tried testing using both AJAX request and Form submission, and I found that generally Form submission takes less time for it to be received. (although I like the concept of AJAX request, where I don't have to change page)

**My question is, is there a way to reduce the time it takes to receive the email? or is there a better way to approach this problem?**

Comment: PHP does not actually send the email, it simply passes the email to the system on the server that does the sending; typically this is a mail queue such as `Exim`. This is the area you want to be exploring if you want to explore this. In my view, I think there are fundamental fixes you should be looking at before reaching this level of detail. For example; stop using `mail()` by default and use a fully featured email header generator such as `swiftmailer` or `phpmailer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking yourself questions where the answer would really lie with a dedicated email provider.

PHP does not "send" the email with `mail()`. PHP delegates to either a SMTP server or `sendmail` on the server PHP is running on; from there, each avenue has additional latency:

- Depending on the version of software providing `sendmail`, your mail may fall into a queue to be processed/sent later
- Depending on the SMTP server, this queue may also exist there
- The recipient SMTP server may have its own processing requirements and ruleset in place, which might introduce more delay.

The "delay" difference you are seeing between AJAX and/or form submission are not due to the method you're doing your request with. They're purely down to statistics and underlying queues.

Switching and effectively "outsourcing" (it's not, but it's the closest word) your outbound email capabilities to a third-party will provide some clarity into this along with a lot of additional features. Most will also allow you to see emails being delayed/not sent/bounced on top, which is another major win. And, to be fair, it's also pretty cheap.